# How to move feature maps across images using slicing?

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am trying to implement the online algorithm of this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.08383.pdf), which is on video classification. This work moves 1/8 of channel feature maps from each image, into the next image, after each convolution operation. The image of the operation has been attached here -

[image]

While trying to implement the same, I have succeeded in extracting out the first 1/8 channel feature maps, but I don't know how to add them to the succeeding image. My code has been attached below -

```
import cv2
import gym
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.autograd as autograd
import torch.nn.functional as F

N = 1 # Batch Size
T = 5 # Time Steps. This means that there are 5 frames in the video
C = 3 # RGB Channels
H = 144 # Height
W = 144 # Width

foo = torch.randn(N*T, C, H, W)

print("Shape of foo = ", foo.shape)
#torch.Size([5, 3, 144, 144])

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 8, 5)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16 * 5 * 5, 120)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
        print("Shape of x = ", x.shape)
        # torch.Size([5, 8, 140, 140])
        shape_extract = x[:, :1,:,:]
        print("Shape of extract = ", shape_extract.shape)
        # torch.Size([5, 1, 140, 140])
        # 1/8 of the channels have been extracted out from above. But how do I transfer these channel features to the next image?

        return x

net = Net()
output = net(foo)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your whole sequence is inside the batch, you can shift the layers using [`torch.roll`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.roll.html) the elements on the first axis.

```
>>> rolled = x.roll(shifts=1, dims=1)
```

Going from this layer layout on `axis=1`:

```
[x_0, x_1, x_2, x_3, ..., x_7]
```

to this one:

```
[x_7, x_0, x_1, x_2, ..., x_6]
```

Then replacing the first element by `x_0`:

```
>>> rolled[:, 0] = x[:, 0]
```

Resulting in this layout:

```
[x_0, x_0, x_1, x_2, ..., x_6]
```

Then you can input tensor `rolled` into the next layer.

---

You can implement a custom layer to wrap this logic:

```
class ShiftLayer(nn.Module):
    def forward(self, x):
        out = x.roll(1, 1)
        out[:, 0] = x[:, 0]
        return out
```

Then use it inside your model:

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        ...
        self.shift = ShiftLayer()

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
        x = self.shift(x)
        x = F.relu(self.conv2(x))
        return x
```